# parser for sql in java

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction

I am planning to create a SQL queries parser.
It can be done just using proper tokenizing and checking for the order.

But I'm planning to do it from something I learned in my Compiler Design courses (but years ago)

I can define the grammar for the queries I want to include, but I need some help in initial guidance, what kind of parser to implement? Top-Down/Bottom-up etc. Which is easier to start with.

Tagging as homework as I'm looking for some guidance.

http://blog.tcx.be/2007/05/writing-parser-overview.html -- I looked at this link which help me on how to proceed. Any other help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A top-down, recursive descent parser is the easiest to understand and thus the easiest to implement if you are coding it by hand.

Have you considered using a parser generator, though? I successfully used [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) in a recent project and would certainly recommend it to others. It has some good tutorials and a nice GUI tool for prototyping your grammar.

Comment: You don't want a hand-coded parser for this. SQL grammars tend to be quite big; you want to use a strong parser generator.  ANTLR is OK, and might come with a SQL grammar already available.

Comment: I'm planning to implement only a small set of features, and may be expand on top of that. Simply to learn this, not to deploy in any prod. environment.

so, Top-Down is the best start point my question right?

Answer (score 1):

A little late for this question, but recently I've been playing with the [SQL Query Parser](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/project_sqldevtools/sqltools_doc/SQL%20Query%20Parser%20User%20documentation.htm) classes, which is part of Eclipse DataTools project. It was a little difficult to me to install it and make it work (I'm not a Java developer) but I managed to and it is very apt to parse very complex queries.